# How to create PIE chart for each record in MS Access Report

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have created a report using report Wizard.There is a column named as percentage complete.I want to generate  Pie chart for each record for this column. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Need at least two values in series for pie chart. In your case you need "complete" and "incomplete". Build a UNION query to generate the "incomplete" value. UNION queries must be built in SQLView of query designer.

```
SELECT ID, [Percentage], "Complete" AS Category FROM table
UNION SELECT ID, 100-[Percentage], "Incomplete" FROM table;
```

Now use that query as source for graph RowSource.

Use the Chart Wizard to build the graph RowSource and set the Master/Child Link properties. Then if you want to can edit the RowSource to be a simpler query (no grouping).
`SELECT [Category], [Rate] FROM [UnionQuery];`